# Clicking on checkbox with Selenium java automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the checkbox below this registration form based on the given code by it doesn't seem to be working.

```
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/request-demo/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll\"]"))).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"doi0\"]")).click();
```

I had also tried `findElement(By.name ("doi")`, this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/request-demo/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut.Seconds(20));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
                
// Accept cookies
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click();
Thread.sleep(5000); 
// Click checkbox
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='doi']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to click on <kbd>Accept Cookie</kbd> button first. And then try to locate and click checkbox.

Refer the code below:

```
driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/request-demo/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        
// Accept cookies
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click();
        
// Click checkbox
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='doi0']"))).click();
```